# Can you easily change the Chip color in Materialize?

Tags: html, meteor, materialize

I'm wanting to set the Chip color dynamically in my view in Materialize, but didn't see anything specifically in the documentation to do it.  is there a simple way?  If not, is it planned?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, **you need to use the css color helper classes.**

[Materialize-Color](http://materializecss.com/color.html)

*Note: Materialize has jquery as dependency therefore I am giving a jquery answer:*

Suppose you have html like this:

```
<div id='testChip' class="chip">
    Tag<i class="close material-icons">close</i>
</div>
```

The following JS will change the chip color (for that one chip):

```
$('#testChip').addClass("teal");
```

For all chips:

```
$('.chip').addClass('teal');
```

If the helper classes colors don't suit your needs create your own color helper and follow the same principle as above:

```
.myBlackColor {
    background-color: #000;
}
```